# awk script to parse between two strings having same name

Tags: awk

Lets say we I have an text like this

```
Hello, 12345
      This is going to be fun
      ABC:172-1345,
           172-1323
      There is more string here.

Hello, 34567
     This is not going to be fun
      ABC:172-2345
     There is more string here
```

Output Should be

```
12345 ABC:172-1345
34567 ABC:172-2345
```

Can we achieve this in `awk`?
We also have to consider the last Hello, as it would not be having another Hello to have the end parse string.

Comment: this is quite broad. Could you specify what is the underlying algorithm and pattern here? `Hello, DIGIT` + one line + `ABC: NUMBER` or something more complex?

Answer (score 0):

Most simply:

```
awk -v RS=Hello, 'NR != 1 { print $1, $NF }'
```

This splits the file into records delimited by `Hello,` and prints the first and last token in each record. `NR == 1` is excluded because it is the empty bit before the first `Hello,`.

Note that multi-character `RS` is not strictly POSIX-conforming, although the most common awks (mawk and gawk) accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print $2,$NF}' file
12345 ABC:172-1345
34567 ABC:172-2345
```